# sql 2008, select from a view as a different user, like owner

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

In sql server 2008, the system views sys.database_role_members and sys.database_principals, only returns the users and group that the current account is allowed to view.

I need to check id a certain account exists, so I need to see all the existing sql account accounts, regardless the permissions of the current account, I mean, just like it used to be in previous versions.

Is there some option like 'EXECUTE AS OWNER' but for views?

Something like

```
create view dbo.vUsers select as owner as

select * from sys.database_principals
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is a "by design" kind of thing for security reasons. Look up "Metadata Visibility Configuration" in BOL for more info on how to work within these constraints.

Comment: Can't you use a stored procedure for this purpose, instead of giving people direct access to the view? The `WHERE` clause *could* be tied to `ORIGINAL_LOGIN` even if the procedure is marked as `EXECUTE AS OWNER`...

Comment: Well, in fact I'm using a system account (something like domain\appService), and they don't have direct access to the view, I'm using it from a stored procedure. So far now I had to give db_securityadmin permissions to that account, because sys.* tables filter what is visible, but I'm trying to avoid it...

Comment: Hey, didn't know about dba.stackexchange, I'll follow your advice (hey, I trust your reputation ;-)

Comment: You should link your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Use a table valued function instead?

It has to be a multistatement function though.
In-line UDFS don't allow `EXECUTE AS` (I guess because they are simply macros like views)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.vUsers ()
RETURNS @dbprincipals TABLE (
    name sysname NOT NULL,
    type char(1) NOT NULL
    )
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @dbprincipals
    SELECT name, type FROM sys.database_principals;

    RETURN;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The more transparent solution I can think so far is to create a couple of tables like sys_database_principals and sys_database_roles,

update the view to point at them

and then define a stored procedure, that will be executed as owner no matter the currently logged account, and woul fill the tables like this

```
create procedure dbo.tmp_fill with execute as owner as
begin

    if exists( select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = 'sys_database_role_members' )
        drop table dbo.sys_database_role_members
    select * into sys_database_role_members from sys.database_role_members

    if exists( select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = 'sys_database_principals' )
        drop table dbo.sys_database_principals
    select * into sys_database_principals from sys.database_principals

end
```